# Are there bikes for rent in Stockholm?

Tags: rental, bicycles, sweden

Is is possible to rent bikes when visiting Stockholm? Is there for example a City Bikes company operating in the city?

Would prefer being able to rent a bike for a few hours, leave it basically anywhere and them pick up a new one where ever I want, paying a low fee for a few days or weeks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several bike renting companies in Stockholm, e.g. [City Bikes](http://www.citybikes.se/) and [Rent a bike](http://www.rentabike.se/indexUk.html).

City Bikes offer several renting locations in and around the city centre, while Rent a bike has one office in the city centre. They both offer flexible renting schedules, from hours to weeks (or seasons, in the case of City Bikes).

Below is a map of City Bike's locations.

[image: Map of City Bikes locations from the website]

Comment: City Bike lost their license in 2019?